# filter array of object on multi conditions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have this array

```
const d = [{
    "type": "price",
    "value": {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 170
    }
}, {
    "type": "name",
    "value": {}
}, {
    "type": "volume",
    "options": [1,2]
}]
```

I want to filter if value doesn't have a value or options is an empty array. So I did

```
d.filter(o => o.value || o.options)
```

I expect `type:name` is gone but why it's still there?

I also tried lodash

```
d.filter(o => !isEmpty(o.value) || !isEmpty(o.options))
```

doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With lodash, you can use `_.reject()` with `_.isEmpty()` to remove items that have an empty `value` object and an empty `options` array:

```js
const arr = [{"type": "price","value": {"min": 0,"max": 170}}, {"type": "name","value": {}}, {"type": "volume","options": [1,2]}]

const result = _.reject(arr, o => _.isEmpty(o.value) && _.isEmpty(o.options))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

With lodash/fp you can easily generate a function that extracts the `value` and the `options`, iterates them with `_.every()` and return `true` (should be removed) if both are empty:

```js
const { reject, flow, props, every, isEmpty } = _

const fn = reject(flow(props(['value', 'options']), every(isEmpty)))

const arr = [{"type": "price","value": {"min": 0,"max": 170}}, {"type": "name","value": {}}, {"type": "volume","options": [1,2]}]

const result = fn(arr)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: if _.reject is opposite of filter, why this doesn't work as expected? ```arr.filter(o => !_.isEmpty(o.value) && !_.isEmpty(o.options))```

Comment: You want to remove only items that don't have *both* `value` and `options`, but include items that have at least one of them. Your condition is - include only if *both* `value` and `options` are not empty. You can change it to `!_.isEmpty(o.value) || !_.isEmpty(o.options)` or to `!(_.isEmpty(o.value) && !_.isEmpty(o.options))`.

Answer (score 2):

`{}` and `[]` are truthy values

```js
console.log(Boolean([]))
console.log(Boolean({}))
```

You can check for length in case of array, in case of object you can get keys or values or entries and check it's length

```js
const d = [{"type": "price","value": {"min": 0,"max": 170}}, {"type": "name","value": {}}, {"type": "volume","options": [1,2]}]

let op = d.filter(o => ( Object.values(o.value || {}) || (o.options || [] )).length)

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```js
const d = [{
    "type": "price",
    "value": {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 170
    }
}, {
    "type": "name",
    "value": {}
}, {
    "type": "volume",
    "options": [1,2]
}]

function notEmpty(n){
   return (!!n ? typeof n === 'object' ? Array.isArray(n) ? !!n.length : !!Object.keys(n).length : true : false);
}

console.log(d.filter(o => notEmpty(o.value) || notEmpty(o.options)));
```

Hope will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Give the custom filter callback where you check for any [`entry`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in `values` property and `options` property.

```js
const d = [
 {
  "type": "price",
  "value": {
   "min": 0,
   "max": 170
  }
 }, 
 {
  "type": "name",
  "value": {}
 }, 
 {
  "type": "volume",
  "options": [1,2]
 }
];


function doesHaveValuesAndOptions(obj) {
 const valueEntries = obj.value ? Object.entries(obj.value) : [],
      options = obj.options || [];
 
 if (!valueEntries.length && !options.length)
  return false;
 
 else if (valueEntries.length || options.length)
  return true;
 
 return false;
}



const res = d.filter(doesHaveValuesAndOptions);
console.log(res);
```